# How to extract make's version number?

Tags: bash, awk, makefile, version

How can I get the numeric version number of `make` from a bash shell?
I tried, among others:

`MAKE_VERSION=$(make --version 2>&1 | awk '/Make/ {print $2}')`

But I get "Make" instead of its version.

This is the output I get from `make --version`:

```
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

In this case I would like to get the string "`4.1`".

Comment: Do you know `MAKE_VERSION` is already defined internally by make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
make_version=$(make --version 2>&1 | awk '/Make/ {print $NF}')
```

as **last field** gives us the version number.

Answer (score 3):

For `make` version's 4.0+ you can use this as well:

```
mver=$(make --eval '$(info $(MAKE_VERSION))' --eval 'all:;' -q)
```

For `make` versions 3.81 and 3.82 (and assuming `bash`) you can use:

```
mver=$(make -f <(echo '$(info $(MAKE_VERSION)) all:;') -q)
```

`make` 3.80 (and older) doesn't have the `$(info)` function so you are left with the approaches in the other answers here or using `$(warning)` and still needing to parse it:

```
mver=$(make -f <(echo '$(warning $(MAKE_VERSION)) all:;') -q 2>&1 | awk '{print $NF}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) and [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
$ make --version | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3
3.81
```